# How to achieve the same SQL behavior through LINQ-to-entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the below two entity classes in my application:

```cs
class Attendance
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string StudentName {get; set;}

  // the linked entity
  public SubjectClass SubjectClass {get; set;} = null; // a nullable column in db
}
```

and

```cs
class SubjectClass
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's ignore attendance times and just assume that whenever a student is present, there is an entry in the attendance table. How can I get a list of `SubjectClass`es with currently present students, grouped with student count per class.
The result is returned as a `List<QueryResult>` DTO like the below:

```
class QueryResult
{
  public int ClassId {get; init;}
  public int ClassCode {get; init;}
  public int PresentStudents {get; init;}
}
```

I have a working SQL query which is listes below:

```sql
SELECT m.Id, m.ClassCode, COUNT(m.ClassId) AS PresentStudents
FROM [SubjectClasses] m 
    INNER JOIN Attendance c ON m.Id = c.Id
GROUP BY m.Id, m.ClassCode
```

This is a .NET 6 application, if that is relevant.

Comment: Are you using Entity framework ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior using LINQ to Entities in your .NET 6 application. First, make sure you have a `DbContext` set up in your application that includes both the `Attendance` and `SubjectClass` entities. Then, you can use LINQ to Entities to write a query that resembles your SQL query:

```
using System.Linq;

// Assuming you have a DbContext instance called "dbContext"
var query = from subjectClass in dbContext.SubjectClasses
            join attendance in dbContext.Attendance on subjectClass.Id equals attendance.SubjectClass.Id
            group subjectClass by new
            {
                subjectClass.Id,
                subjectClass.Code
            } into g
            select new QueryResult
            {
                ClassId = g.Key.Id,
                ClassCode = g.Key.Code,
                PresentStudents = g.Count()
            };

List<QueryResult> results = query.ToList();
```

through lambda syntax:

```
var results = dbContext.SubjectClasses 
    .Join(dbContext.Attendance, 
        subjectClass => subjectClass.Id, 
        attendance => attendance.SubjectClass.Id, 
        (subjectClass, attendance) => subjectClass) 
    .GroupBy(
        subjectClass => new { subjectClass.Id, subjectClass.Code }) 
    .Select(g => new QueryResult 
    { 
        ClassId = g.Key.Id, 
        ClassCode = g.Key.Code, 
        PresentStudents = g.Count() 
    }) 
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible through lambda syntax?

Comment: var results = dbContext.SubjectClasses
    .Join(dbContext.Attendance, subjectClass => subjectClass.Id, attendance => attendance.SubjectClass.Id, (subjectClass, attendance) => subjectClass)
    .GroupBy(subjectClass => new { subjectClass.Id, subjectClass.Code })
    .Select(g => new QueryResult
    {
        ClassId = g.Key.Id,
        ClassCode = g.Key.Code,
        PresentStudents = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();

Comment: Can you update your answer and add the lamba syntax at the end of your answer, in a nicely formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

First, there seems to be a small issue in your SQL. You are joining Attendance using `Attendance.Id = SubjectClasses.Id` condition. That doesn't seem right. You should probably join by `Attendance.SubjectClassId = SubjectClasses.Id`. This is probably what it should be instead:

```
SELECT m.Id AS CLassId, m.ClassCode, COUNT(m.Id) AS PresentStudents
FROM [SubjectClasses] m 
    INNER JOIN Attendance c ON m.Id = c.SubjectClassId
GROUP BY m.Id, m.ClassCode
```

Here is how you can write it in EF Core:

```
from subcjectClass in _yourContext.SubjcectClasses
join attendance in _yourContext.Attendance
on subjectClass.Id equals attendance.SubjectClassId
group subcjectClass by new { subjectClass.Id, subjectClass.ClassCode } into classGroup
select new QueryResult
{
   ClassId = classGroup.Key.Id,
   ClassCode = classGroup.Key.ClassCode,
   PresentStudents = classGroup.Count()
}
```

**Update**

Here is how to do it with lambda syntax. In the example below, the join is done with the **Include** method. The Include method does INNER JOIN if the foreign key that it uses for joining is not nullable. If the foreign key is nullable, it does LEFT JOIN. That is the reason there is a **Where** method call in the example below to make sure that it works similar to an INNER JOIN regardless if your foreign key is nullable or not. However, if your foreign key is not nullable, please remove the Where method call.

```
_yourContext.Attendance
    .Include(a => a.SubjectClass)
    // Delete the Where method if SubjectClassId is a not null FK.
    .Where(a => a.SubjectClass != null)
    .GroupBy(a=> new { a.SubjectClass.Id, a.SubjectClass.ClassCode })
    .Select(classGroup => new  
    {
        ClassId = classGroup.Key.Id,
        ClassCode = classGroup.Key.ClassCode,
        PresentStudents = classGroup.Count()
     })
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible through lambda syntax?

Comment: @user21996911 I updated my answer to include a version with lambda syntax.

Answer (score 0):

While you can copy that syntax into Linq, it might be easier to just use a subquery

```sql
_yourContext.SubjcectClasses
    .Select(sc => new QueryResult {
        ClassId = classGroup.Key.Id,
        ClassCode = classGroup.Key.ClassCode,
        PresentStudents = _yourContext.Attendance
            .Where(att => sc.Id == att.Id)
            .Count()
    });
```

The equivalent SQL is

```sql
SELECT
  sc.Id,
  sc.ClassCode,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Attendance att
    WHERE att.Id = sc.Id
  ) AS PresentStudents
FROM SubjectClasses sc;
```

Note that the semantics are slightly different: this will return results even when the `PresentStudents` count is `0`.

Comment: I think this one will be slower than grouping and counting attendance that way.

Comment: And would you think that? As you can see the query plans are almost identical, both using a Nested Loop / Index Seek https://dbfiddle.uk/9uSYtzAL

Comment: thanks for sharing the query plans. I see they are similar. I didn't do any benchmarking, just said that based on my experience with large data sets, subqueries in selects tend to be slower.

Comment: @developer-partners It tends to depend on the indexing. If there is an obvious index to use then it will generally be used, but if there is no index then subqueries tend to force a naive Nested Loop (without a Seek) which is indeed slow. Obviously YMMV you always need to examine the query plan.